# SpeechSynthesis not defined on Android but is defined in Electron (Windows)

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am attempting to get Text to Speech to work in my app, which is for Android and Electron. The code I am using works in Electron but not in Android.

I have attempted basically everything from the Mozilla page on SpeechSynthesis, but it keeps telling me that SpeechSynthesis is not defined when on Android.

```
private playAudio() {
    if ('speechSynthesis' in window) {
        console.log("The API is installed");
        var ssu = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance("hello world");
        window.speechSynthesis.speak(ssu);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone comes back to this, I ended up using cordova-plugin-tts, which works on Android.